# Android monkey causes Application Not Responding in native library

Tags: android, android-monkey

I get this when running `monkey -v -p package.name --throttle 1 --pct-syskeys 0 100000`.

I suppose this is not my own code? It appears to be Android's drawing code.
Jellybean 4.1.1.

```
DALVIK THREADS:
(mutexes: tll=0 tsl=0 tscl=0 ghl=0)

"main" prio=5 tid=1 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41a5b568 self=0x41a4b9f8
  | sysTid=20523 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1074767408
  | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=1189 stm=194 core=0
  #00  pc 0000dc70  /system/lib/libc.so (__futex_syscall3+8)
  #01  pc 00012bd4  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait_relative+48)
  #02  pc 00012c30  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait+60)
  #03  pc 00052bb5  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmChangeStatus(Thread*, ThreadStatus
)+68)
  #04  pc 0004ce7b  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+398)
  #05  pc 00027260  /system/lib/libdvm.so
  #06  pc 0002bb38  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+180)
  #07  pc 0005f877  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInvokeMethod(Object*, Method const*, ArrayObject*, ArrayObject*, ClassObject*, bool)+374)
  #08  pc 00066d4d  /system/lib/libdvm.so
  #09  pc 00027260  /system/lib/libdvm.so
  #10  pc 0002bb38  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+180)
  #13  pc 0004698d  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
  #14  pc 0004746f  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, char const*)+390)
  #15  pc 00000dcf  /system/bin/app_process
  #16  pc 00016eab  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+38)
  #17  pc 00000b34  /system/bin/app_process
  at android.view.Surface.unlockCanvasAndPost(Native Method)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.drawSoftware(ViewRootImpl.java:2267)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2151)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2019)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1830)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:998)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4212)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: `monkey -v -p package --throttle 1 --pct-syskeys 0 100000`


Thanks for asking, I added to the question.